# How to directly access GNSS sensor in iOS

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, android-gnss

Is there any way, to directly access the internal GNSS sensor data of iOS devices? I don't want to access the already processed GNSS locations from the CoreLocation API.

In Android it's possible to access these raw measurements (pseudorange, carrier phase, doppler, CNR). Is it possible to bypass CoreLocation and access these values of the GNSS chip?

Are there any news, if this will be possible in future iOS versions?

The internal position estimation of iOS is a blackbox and i want to implement my own position estimation for research purposes.

Comment: No, location is abstracted through core location. I doubt this will ever change.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this @Christian?